# Would a "Permanence" spell in 5e be overpowered?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

I know that other role playing games have a *Permanence* spell that has a sole purpose of giving other spells a permanent duration, but 5e seems to have no such spell.
Is this because it would be overpowered or is it something that I have not noticed?

Comment: Have you read through this thread? https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104743/how-are-spells-made-permanent-in-5e The CoDzilla effect in the answer "This is how 3.5 broke" might be of particular interest to you.

Comment: Related: [How exploitable/balanced is this homebrew spell: Spell Permanency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/144270/52137)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**It would not only be overpowered, but it would also break the game design philosophy of 5e.**

5e is a system that avoids stacking effects. If you want a small selection of permanent spells you have the options of [Wish](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wish#content), creating magical items and granting epic boons.

While this question is not strictly a duplicate, it has been answered in the following threads: [How are spells made permanent in 5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/104743/how-are-spells-made-permanent-in-5e) and [How exploitable/balanced is this homebrew spell: Spell Permanency?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144270/how-exploitable-balanced-is-this-homebrew-spell-spell-permanency?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The most notable design-philosophy considerations in 5e are how concentration spells avoid stacking effects, how advantage rolls avoid stacking, and how 5e generally streamlines its design.

**Further considerations** are how this spell would affect the world in which the game takes places. GMs have divergent opinions on whether a world has to be alive containing economic-, taxonomic- and ecological systems that are internally consistent. Permanency of any kind has everlasting effects in a society in which it is available, even when it is restricted to affect a limited amount of spells.